# declaring and instantiating Rectangles and Circles

Tags: c#, drawing

Is there anyway to declare and instantiate an ellipse in C#? I can do it with a rectangle as shown bellow:

```
private Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
```

Is there a way for me to do the following(or something similar)?:

```
private Ellipse circ = new Ellipse();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "Rectangle" is an abstract set of coordinates.

In contrast to "Drawing.DrawRectangle()", "Drawing.FillRectangle()" and "Drawing.DrawEllipse()", which are graphical primitives you can draw on a canvas.

I think you're looking for the "Draw" primitives:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cy2c290%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

PS:
The graphics methods "DrawEllipse()" and "FillEllipse()" can take "Rectangle()" coordinates as input parameters :)